# Rails Feedjira gem unable to parse RSS with xml-stylesheet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri, feedjira

I use Feedjira gem v2.0 in my Ruby on Rails project to parse RSS feeds. Recently, I have encountered this feed https://www.deutschlandfunknova.de/podcast/update which it is unable to parse. If I omit following line from the feed, then it successfully parse.

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" media="screen" href="https://www.deutschlandfunknova.de/podcast.xsl?>
```

I used Feedjira::Feed.parse(response.body) to parse the feed but it returns an empty `Feedjira::Parser::ITunesRSS` Object whereas it should have parsed the document.